# Como ordenar json em php

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho o exemplo do json que estou usando abaixo:

---

```
[
  {
    "unidade": "124",
    "bloco": "Bloco B"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "21",
    "bloco": "Bloco A"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "94",
    "bloco": "Bloco A"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "31",
    "bloco": "Bloco B"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "24",
    "bloco": "Bloco B"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "132",
    "bloco": "Bloco A"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "12",
    "bloco": "Bloco A"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "00",
    "bloco": "Bloco B"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "43",
    "bloco": "Bloco B"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "63",
    "bloco": "Bloco A"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "32",
    "bloco": "Bloco B"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "174",
    "bloco": "Bloco B"
  }
]
```

preciso ordenar esses dados de modo que priorize o Bloco (primeiro o A e depois o B) e após isso ordene a unidade unidade. Já consegui resolver a unidade, mas não consigo resolver o bloco. Meu código está conforme abaixo:

```
<?php

$jsonObj = json_decode($dados);
sort($jsonObj);
foreach ($jsonObj as $buildings){
    echo"$buildings->unidade" "$buildings->bloco";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lucas, segue código. O comentei o código pra você.

```
<?php

//Criando Array
$resultados ='[
  {
    "unidade": "124",
    "bloco": "Bloco B"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "21",
    "bloco": "Bloco A"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "94",
    "bloco": "Bloco A"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "31",
    "bloco": "Bloco B"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "24",
    "bloco": "Bloco B"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "132",
    "bloco": "Bloco A"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "12",
    "bloco": "Bloco A"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "00",
    "bloco": "Bloco B"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "43",
    "bloco": "Bloco B"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "63",
    "bloco": "Bloco A"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "32",
    "bloco": "Bloco B"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "174",
    "bloco": "Bloco B"
  }
]';
    $arr = json_decode($resultados, true);


    $sort = array();
    foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
        $sort['unidade'][$k] = $v['unidade'];
        $sort['bloco'][$k] = $v['bloco'];
    }

    //aqui é realizado a ordenação do array
    array_multisort($sort['bloco'], SORT_ASC, $sort['unidade'], SORT_ASC,$arr);

    //abaixo é listado o resultado ordenado  
    foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
        echo 'Unidade: ' . $sort['unidade'][$k] = $v['unidade'] . ' - ';
        echo $sort['bloco'][$k] = $v['bloco'] . '<br>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Aqui tem um exemplo de como fazer isso:

```html
<?php
$resultados ='[
  {
    "unidade": "124",
    "bloco": "Bloco B"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "21",
    "bloco": "Bloco A"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "94",
    "bloco": "Bloco A"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "31",
    "bloco": "Bloco B"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "24",
    "bloco": "Bloco B"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "132",
    "bloco": "Bloco A"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "12",
    "bloco": "Bloco A"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "00",
    "bloco": "Bloco B"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "43",
    "bloco": "Bloco B"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "63",
    "bloco": "Bloco A"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "32",
    "bloco": "Bloco B"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "174",
    "bloco": "Bloco B"
  }
]';
$arr = json_decode($resultados, true);
$sort = array();
foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
$sort['unidade'][$k] = $v['unidade'];
$sort['bloco'][$k] = $v['bloco'];
}
array_multisort($sort['bloco'], SORT_ASC, $sort['unidade'], SORT_ASC,$arr);
print_r($arr);


?>
```

Comment: Deu certo a lógica, mas ainda estou com dificuldade a respeito do Print_r(). Precisava que a saída do programa fosse assim:

11 Bloco A
12 Bloco A
13 Bloco A 

Sabe como eu posso fazer isso?

Comment: @lucasmenezes vc quer ordenar primeiro o bloco e depois as unidades, isto?

Comment: @LeandroAlfredo Isso mesmo Leandro, o Bloco tem prioridade no momento de fazer o ordenamento. Mas preciso que ele saia sem aquela saída cheia de informação sobre o array igual essa:

Array ( [0] => Array ( [unidade] => 11 [bloco] => Bloco A ) [1] => Array ( [unidade] => 12 [bloco] => Bloco A ) [2]

*Como ainda sou iniciante em PHP não manjo muito em relação ao tratamento dessas saídas.

Comment: ah sim, vou postar nova resposta pra vc

Answer (score 2):

Pode ser feito usando [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) pra fazer a ordenação, basta implementar a comparação da ordenação tu mesmo, na lógica que usei foi retornar o bloco com menor unidade quando está sendo comparado dois elementos do mesmo bloco, caso contrário comparado o nome do bloco.

```
$json = '[ { "unidade": "124", "bloco": "Bloco B" }, { "unidade": "21", "bloco": "Bloco A" }, { "unidade": "94", "bloco": "Bloco A" }, { "unidade": "31", "bloco": "Bloco B" }, { "unidade": "24", "bloco": "Bloco B" }, { "unidade": "132", "bloco": "Bloco A" }, { "unidade": "12", "bloco": "Bloco A" }, { "unidade": "00", "bloco": "Bloco B" }, { "unidade": "43", "bloco": "Bloco B" }, { "unidade": "63", "bloco": "Bloco A" }, { "unidade": "32", "bloco": "Bloco B" }, { "unidade": "174", "bloco": "Bloco B" } ]';
$json = json_decode($json, true);

usort($json, function($x, $y) { 
    if ($x['bloco'] === $y['bloco']) {
        return $x['unidade'] > $y['unidade']  ? +1 : -1;
    } else {
        return $x['bloco'] > $y['bloco']  ? +1 : -1;
    }
});

var_dump($json);
```

Answer (score 2):

A função [`usort`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.usort.php) dá bastante controle a ordenação. Essa função irá ordenar um array pelos valores usando uma função de classificação definida pelo usuário.

Se o array precisar ser ordenado utilizando um critério peculiar, você deve usar essa função.

A comparação é feita de dois em dois elementos($a e $b) e segue a seguinte tabela de retornos:

- -1 : se `$a < $b`
- 0 : se `$a == $b`
- 1 : se `$a > $b`

Resposta:

```
<?php
$resultados ='[
  {
    "unidade": "124",
    "bloco": "Bloco B"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "21",
    "bloco": "Bloco A"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "94",
    "bloco": "bLoCo a"  //<--- Não falha, o algorítimo é insensível a capitalização
  },
  {
    "unidade": "31",
    "bloco": "Bloco B"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "24",
    "bloco": "Bloco B"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "132",
    "bloco": "Bloco A"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "12",
    "bloco": "Bloco C"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "00",
    "bloco": "Bloco B"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "43",
    "bloco": "Bloco C"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "63",
    "bloco": "Bloco A"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "32",
    "bloco": "Bloco B"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "174",
    "bloco": "Bloco B"
  }
]';


$arr = json_decode($resultados, false);

usort($arr, function($a, $b) {   
    // Primeiro compara os blocos
    $cmp2 = strcasecmp($a->bloco , $b->bloco);
      if ($cmp2 === 0) { // Se os blocos forem iguais compara as unidades
        if ($a->unidade < $b->unidade) {
          return -1;
      } elseif ($a->unidade > $b->unidade) {
          return 1;
      } else return 0;
    } else return $cmp2; //Se os blocos forem diferentes retorna a comparação entre si.  
});

// Imprime os resultados
echo PHP_EOL;
foreach($arr as $u) {
    echo 'Unidade: ' . $u->unidade . ' - ';
    echo $u->bloco  . PHP_EOL;
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Se é Laravel façamos do jeito laravel, usando collection você pode fazer algo como abaixo.

```
 $a = '[
  {
    "unidade": "124",
    "bloco": "Bloco B"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "21",
    "bloco": "Bloco A"
  },
  {
    "unidade": "94",
    "bloco": "Bloco A"
  }
]';

 $b = json_decode($a);


 $collection = collect($b);
 $sorted = $collection->sortBy('bloco');
 print_r($sorted->values()->all());//dump|dd|var_dump ...
```

Não tive como testar pois estou sem o Laravel na minha máquina. Recomendo ver a doc
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-collect